# Box: Is there a way to download webdocs and Google documents in Office format?

Tags: box-api

Is there a way to download Box's webdocs and Google's gdocs as Word documents, and Google's gsheets as Excel spreadsheets?

I download files as follows:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpMethod getMethod = new GetMethod("https://api.box.com/2.0/files/fileId/data");
getMethod.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "BoxAuth api_key=" + API_KEY + "&auth_token=" + authToken);
client.executeMethod(getMethod);
```

Is there a header or parameter I can include that will allow export in the specified format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have the capability to convert to Excel or other formats available via API.  Thanks for asking.  If we see enough business demand for it, then we will consider offering it.